# TypeScript: get a property from conditional types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a value that either can exist or not on the property. So I have 2 types: `EmptyUser` and `UserResponse`.

`EmptyUser` interface only has one property.
`UserResponse` interface has a lot of properties AND `id` property that I need.

Then in my function I'm trying to use `id`, but I can't get it from the created types. Below is the example of code:

```
interface EmptyUser {
  // only this property
  unauthorized: boolean;
}

interface UserResponse {
  // ...a lot of different properties and
  id: number;
}

export type UsersType = EmptyUser | UserResponse;

interface State {
  users: UsersType,
}
```

then in my code I'm trying to get property `id` from `state.users`:

```
const { id }: UsersType = state.users;
```

and I receive an error: **TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'UsersType'.**

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions).

Answer (score 0):

With `|` you are saying that `UsersType` can be any one of `EmptyUser` or `UserResponse`. So `id` can not be guaranteed to be in `UsersType`.

If you do it individually, with either one of the types you will not have an issue. [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOYCeBVAZ2mQG8BYAKGWQHobkB7EAGx2TAAtgDlMoHM0XJWoBXEHFGcGUYAC8IAEwBcyAEYMGzCHBABuSgF9KlUJFiIUhaACUIBTEyKkRtegDpPcZMwZhGMMiKwDAw0BDgvPyCUGDA9si6iq7AKsggouhq0AYUxhSUEAAejrHsOILI1lAEACoVKAC8aFi41cgAPlVEUHYOThC5puDQ8EjIAMpgcJAuVMiiPQSq1XUNADRGJhTa-gTTs6pTM01zYkvIquTz1KmXyABMmzcLElIcMvJK9-DMRK75QxDCgIJz+EjIO6GFZLeqVZr7E7uRbQAh6IA)

```
interface EmptyUser {
  // only this property
  unauthorized: boolean;
}

interface UserResponse {
  // ...a lot of different properties and
  id: number;
}

export type UsersType = UserResponse;

interface State {
  users: UsersType,
}

let state : State = {
  users : {
    id : 2
  }
};

const { id }: UsersType = state.users;
```

But if you want an item to have properties from both, you need `&` intersection type.

```
interface EmptyUser {
  // only this property
  unauthorized: boolean;
}

interface UserResponse {
  // ...a lot of different properties and
  id: number;
}

export type UsersType = EmptyUser & UserResponse;

interface State {
  users: UsersType,
}

let state : State = {
  users : {
    id : 2,
    unauthorized : false
  }
};

const { id }: UsersType = state.users;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOYCeBVAZ2mQG8BYAKGWQHobkB7EAGx2TAAtgDlMoHM0XJWoBXEHFGcGUYAC8IAEwBcyAEYMGzCHBABuSgF9KlUJFiIUhaACUIBTEyKkRtegDpPcZMwZhGMMiKwDAw0BDgvPyCUGDA9si6iq7AKsggouhq0AYUxhSUEAAejrHsOILI1lAEACoVKAC8aFi41cgAZFVEUHYOThC5puDQ8EjIAMpgcJAuVMiiPQSq1XUNADRGJhTa-gTTs6pTM01zYkvIquTz1KmXyABMmzcLElIcMvJK9-DMRK75QxDCgIJz+EjIO6GFZLeqVZr7E7uRbQAh6IA)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
interface EmptyUser {
   // only this property
   unauthorized: boolean;
}

interface UserResponse {
   // ...a lot of different properties and
   id: number;
}

type UsersType = EmptyUser | UserResponse;

 interface State {
   users: UsersType,
 }

 let state : State = {
   users : {
      id : 2,
      unauthorized : false
   }
 };

const { id }  = state.users as UserResponse;
console.log(id);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&filetype=ts#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOYCeBVAZ2mQG8BYAKGWQHobkB7EAGx2TAAtgDlMoHM0XJWoBXEHFGcGUYAC8IAEwBcyAEYMGzCHBABuSgF9KlUJFiIUhaACUIBTEyKkRtegDpPcZMwZhGMMiKwDAw0BDgvPyCUGDA9si6iq7AKsggouhq0AYUxhSUuILI1lAEACo4xQC8aFi4pcgAPiVEUHYOThC5puDQ8EjIAMpgcJAuVMiibQSqpRVVEAA0RiYU2v4Eo5AAjMiqI2MoteST09A8qqfU1Kn7yABMK5NiElIcMvJK9-DMRK75Qw9CgIJz%20EjIO6Gai1LZHHbuc5lRI8UodRwgIjA0GYrQQdy%20ADmAApUgBKPRAA)